# AttributeError: 'EC2' object has no attribute 'tag_resources'

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto3

I run following code and get error:

```
#!python -u

from boto3 import client

def is_tags():
 response = client('ec2', 'us-east-1').tag_resources(
 ResourceARNList=[
 'arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1::image/ami-55ef662f'
    ],
    Tags=[
        {
         'Key': 'Name',
         'Value': 'john',
        },
    ],
    )    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    is_tags()
```

It is throwing the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'EC2' object has no attribute 'tag_resources'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the library incorrectly, the client object has no attribute called `tag_resources`, due to which the call to it is failing.

You can refer the correct usage from the [boto3 documentation for Tag in EC2](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#tag):

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', 'us-east-1')
tag = ec2.Tag('resource_id','key','value')
```

---

**EDIT**: I am not sure if there is a single API for tagging multiple type of resources that consistently works. You seem to be following [this API](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/resourcegroupstaggingapi.html#ResourceGroupsTaggingAPI.Client.tag_resources), in which case, you have to define your [client correctly](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/resourcegroupstaggingapi.html#ResourceGroupsTaggingAPI.Client), like:

```
client = boto3.client('resourcegroupstaggingapi', 'us-east-1')
```

Comment: I actually want to tag resources with just one syntax...Is it possible..I got something like this in documentation:- response = client.tag_resources(
    ResourceARNList=[
        'string',
    ],
    Tags={
        'string': 'string'
    }
)    Can"t we use this same syntax to add tags for resources.

Comment: I want same syntax to be used for ec2,s3,etc etc resources

Comment: @gulshankumar I am not sure if there is a single API for that.. You seem to be following http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/resourcegroupstaggingapi.html#ResourceGroupsTaggingAPI.Client.tag_resources , in which case, you have to define client like http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/resourcegroupstaggingapi.html#ResourceGroupsTaggingAPI.Client

Comment: yes the query has been resolved..thanks for the suggestion